# Error of: A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SocketIO'

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

I'm trying to create a socket io app, and I'm using `adhara_socket_io`. I added the code from the example on the pub.dev site, and I'm gettin an error. Here's the code:

```
SocketIOManager manager = SocketIOManager();
SocketIO socket = manager.createInstance('http://192.168.1.2:7000/');  // I get the error here
socket.onConnect((data){
  print("connected...");
  print(data);
  socket.emit("message", ["Hello world!"]);
});
socket.connect();
```

I get two errors. First one:

> A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of
>   type 'SocketIO'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
>   right-hand type to 'SocketIO'

And the second one:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type
>   'SocketOptions'

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that this guy manager.createInstance returns a future so you should place await right in front of it to wait for the future to be resolved. Something like this:

```
SocketIO socket = await manager.createInstance('http://192.168.1.2:7000/');
```

If this code is inside of a function you should marks this function as async

Answer (score 0):

```
   //i think like Javascript for using await just wrap your function with async keyword.
   fn() async{
       SocketIOManager manager = SocketIOManager();
       SocketIO socket = await manager.createInstance('http://192.168.1.2:7000/');  
       socket.onConnect((data){
         print("connected...");
         print(data);
         socket.emit("message", ["Hello world!"]);
       });
       socket.connect();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.